# Как сделать линии видимыми? Python -> PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qpainter

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии определенной клавиши стали видны линии, которые я нанес в прямоугольнике?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from random import randint


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(700, 700)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = randint(260, 440)
        self.y = 200

    def up(self):
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.x += 2
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x -= 2
        elif  event.key() == Qt.Key_F:            # Я сделал так, но что-то неправильно
            self.qp.setPen(QColor(13, 239, 66))
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.up)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.qp.drawRect(260, 455, 180, 110)

        self.qp.drawLine(260, 510, 440, 510)
        self.qp.drawLine(350, 455, 350, 570)
        if self.x > 440 or self.x < 260:             
            self.qp.setPen(QColor(190, 190, 190))
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x, 505, self.x, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 5, 505, self.x + 5, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 10, 505, self.x + 10, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 15, 505, self.x + 15, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 5, 505, self.x - 5, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 10, 505, self.x - 10, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 15, 505, self.x - 15, 515)



StyleSheet = """
QMainWindow{
    border-image: url(11.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Чтобы после нажатия была вот такая вот картина:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from random import randint


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(700, 700)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = randint(260, 440)
        self.y = 200

    def up(self):
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.x += 2
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x -= 2
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.up)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.qp.drawRect(260, 455, 180, 110)
        self.qp.setPen(QColor(13, 239, 66))
        self.qp.drawLine(260, 510, 440, 510)
        self.qp.drawLine(350, 455, 350, 570)
        if self.x > 440 or self.x < 260:             
            self.qp.setPen(QColor(190, 190, 190))
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x, 505, self.x, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 5, 505, self.x + 5, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 10, 505, self.x + 10, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 15, 505, self.x + 15, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 5, 505, self.x - 5, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 10, 505, self.x - 10, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 15, 505, self.x - 15, 515)


StyleSheet = """
QMainWindow{
    border-image: url(11.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте нажать на клавишу `Qt.Key_F`, а теперь на нее еще раз.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from random import randint


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(700, 600)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = randint(260, 440)
        self.y = 200
        
        self.flag_Key_F = False                                          # +++

    def up(self):
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.x += 2
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x -= 2
        elif  event.key() == Qt.Key_F:              
#            self.qp.setPen(QColor(13, 239, 66))    # Я сделал так, но что-то неправильно
            self.flag_Key_F = not self.flag_Key_F   # +++
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.up)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.qp.drawRect(260, 455, 180, 110)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        if self.flag_Key_F:
            self.qp.setPen(QColor(13, 239, 66))
        else:
            self.qp.setPen(QColor(0, 0, 0))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.qp.drawLine(260, 510, 440, 510)
        self.qp.drawLine(350, 455, 350, 570)
        
        if self.x > 440 or self.x < 260:             
            self.qp.setPen(QColor(190, 190, 190))
            
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x, 505, self.x, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 5, 505, self.x + 5, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 10, 505, self.x + 10, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x + 15, 505, self.x + 15, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 5, 505, self.x - 5, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 10, 505, self.x - 10, 515)
        self.qp.drawLine(self.x - 15, 505, self.x - 15, 515)


StyleSheet = """
QMainWindow{
    border-image: url(11.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ZheD1s что не так ?

Comment: всё идеально работает спасибо. self.flag_Key_F = not self.flag_Key_F можете объяснить этот момент?